How do I share a piece of data between a series of CheckoutUIExtensions?
I am building a series of shopify checkout UI extensions, because they have pulled the rug out from under us Shopify Plus customers and removed the ability to modify our checkout.liquid files. The system I am building is a rewards/points keeping system that tracks and rewards people for purchasing certain items.
[[extensions.targeting]]
module = "./src/Banner.tsx"
target = "purchase.checkout.block.render"

[[extensions.targeting]]
module = "./src/LineItems.tsx"
target = "purchase.checkout.cart-line-item.render-after"

[[extensions.targeting]]
module = "./src/Calculator.tsx"
target = "purchase.checkout.reductions.render-after"

All I want to do is share a single integer between all 3 components. This integer is just a multiplier for a points keeping/rewards system. I am new to react and have recently learned of useContext. But I'm not sure how to share it between 3 .tsx files.
Really all my components kind of look like this below and I just want that one variable to be shared between all 3 of these components so that I can update it in one place. We frequently change these multipliers based on promotions so having it in a single spot is ideal.
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';

import {
  Heading,
  useApi,
  InlineLayout,
  Text,
  View,
  useApplyDiscountCodeChange,
  useDiscountCodes,
  useAppMetafields,
  reactExtension,
} from '@shopify/ui-extensions-react/checkout';

export default reactExtension(
  'purchase.checkout.reductions.render-after',
  () => <Extension />,
);

function Extension() {
  const { extension, lines } = useApi();

  const productMetaDatas = useAppMetafields({
    type: "product",
    namespace: "custom",
    key: "entry_override_arbitrary_value"
  });

  let multiplier = 40;
  let [messageHeader, setMessageHeader] = useState('Total Entries');
  let [message, setMessage] = useState('You will receive 40 entries for every $1 spent!');

  const discountCodes = useDiscountCodes();
  const ApplyDiscountCodeChange = useApplyDiscountCodeChange();

  useEffect(() => {
    let tempEntries = 0;

    lines.current.forEach(function (cartLineTarget) {
      // Get the product ID from the cart line item
      const productId = cartLineTarget?.merchandise?.product?.id;
      if (!productId) {
        return;
      }

      const productMetaData = productMetaDatas.find(({ target }) => {
        return `gid://shopify/Product/${target.id}` === productId;
      });

      if (productMetaData?.metafield.value) {
        tempEntries += parseInt(productMetaData.metafield.value) * cartLineTarget.quantity;
      } else {
        tempEntries += Math.floor(cartLineTarget.cost.totalAmount.amount) * cartLineTarget.quantity * multiplier;
      }

    });

    const bonusDiscountCodes = [
      { 'FREESHIPPING2024': 50 },
      { 'CLOWNSHOES': 20 },
    ];

    if (discountCodes.length > 0) {

      const isActiveDiscountCodeInBonus = bonusDiscountCodes.some(discountCodeObj =>
        Object.keys(discountCodeObj).includes(discountCodes[0].code)
      );

      if (isActiveDiscountCodeInBonus) {
        tempEntries += 50;
      }

    }

    setMessage(tempEntries);

  }, [message, messageHeader, lines, productMetaDatas, discountCodes]);

  return (
    <InlineLayout columns={['fill', '20%']}>
      <View>
        <Heading level="2">{messageHeader}</Heading>
      </View>
      <View inlineAlignment="end">
        <Text appearance="info">{message}</Text>
      </View>
    </InlineLayout>
  );
}

Right now I've just duplicated the declared "multiplier" variable between all 3 components. But that's not an ideal situation. I know there is a simple solution but I cant for the life of me figure it out.

Did you try using Order Metafield (useMetafield - https://shopify.dev/docs/api/checkout-ui-extensions/2023-07/react-hooks/metafields/usemetafields)?
